# Validate user account via email link in symfony2

Tags: symfony, email-validation

I'm looking for a basic explanation of how could I do this with symfony2, since there is no decent documentation in the web about this. I know how could I do the process with plain php, but I don't know where to start with symfony2.

Any help would be really appreciated, guys.

Thanks!

To clarify what I'm looking for: once the user completes the registration process, send an automatic email with a link to activate his account

Comment: Are you using the FOSUserBundle? It ships with this feature.

Comment: I didn't hear about it! I'm gonna try it... thanks!

Answer (score 5):

FOSUserBundle has this feature by default.

You can do it on your own:

- Create a user specific secure hash and store it in the database at registration.
- Send an email to user containing a link with that hash: `myapp.com/signup/token/..(token here).../`
- Create the relevant route to the controller that will check the hash, pass the token in the url to the controller as variable.
- Check if the hash is correct in the controller and do the relevant action.